# If concentration inequalities correspond to non-asymptotic probability, what do anti-concentration inequalities correspond to?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, independence, concentration-of-measure

**Concentration of measures** is a niche in statistical probability theory, most notable for deriving **concentration inequalities**. I'm still trying to grasp its underlying motivation and premise compared to traditional statistics.

If concentration inequalities correspond to *non-asymptotic* probability theory, what do **anti-concentration inequalities** correspond to?